# What is a good design for making an NFT marketplace ecosystem or architecture?

Tags: solidity, nft, architecture

My question is short:

> How an Ethereum smart contract, my backend and clients should be connected to each other to do something in a net?

For example, what things should be authoritative by a centralized server backend or can clients send requests to smart contracts without any server connection?

An example:
In a football game, the user has a football player as an NFT that wants to sell it to another player. can this transaction do totally authoritative by my server or do they need to directly communicate to the smart contract and then send a request to my backend side and my backend side needs to do its own validation by connecting to a smart contract?

Comment: Hi virtuoso! Welcome to Ethereum Stackexchange! I've changed the title since having in the title "right" or "best" make the question subjective.

Comment: There's no perfect setup. In an ideal decentralized world you'll only need a smart contract, frontend and backend won't be needed. But people not used to interacting with a contract will have it complicated. Also contracts are expensive and it might be necessary to provide a more amiable frontend for the users.

Answer (score 0):

Sir, This cannot be explained in an answer here because setting up a marketplace is very complex.
I suggest doing a lot of research. I don't know your skill level but from what I read you need more understanding of the core technical concepts regarding DApp development. If you type in dapp development in YouTube you will get tons of video's that will teach you everything you need to know to get started. Good luck!

Comment: i dont think that is much complicated. i already know some info but tring to find some best practices.